# jQuery $.get() JSON function executing but won't result anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dialog

The page called when executing the `$.getJSON()` is doing its job everytime I call the script (when the user clicks on a link/button), although the function associated to it won't do anything!
 This is inside the `Script.php` file:

```
$('a.addCategorie').click(function (e)
    {

        e.preventDefault();
        var dialog='<div id="Dialog_AddCategory">\
        <div id="tableContainer">\
        <table class="categoryTable">\
        <thead>\
        <tr>\
        <th>Ordre</th>\
        <th>Catégorie</th>\
        <th>    </th>\
        </tr>\
        </thead>\
        <tbody>\
        <?php 
            $sql="SELECT nom, ordre FROM category ORDER BY ordre";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>". $row['ordre'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". utf8_decode($row['nom']) ."</td>";
                echo "<td id=\"" . $row['ordre'] . "\" class=\"deleteCat\"></td>";
                echo "</tr>\\\n";
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>\
        </table></div>\
        <div id="addCategorie_Form">\
        <form>\
        <label for="nomCategorie">Nom de la catégorie</label>\
        <input type="text" name="nomCategorie" id="nomCategorie"/>\
        <label for="ordreCategorie">Ordre</label>\
        <input type="text" name="ordreCategorie" id="ordreCategorie"/>\
        </form>\
        </div></div>';
        $('body').append(dialog);
$( '#Dialog_AddCategory' ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 800,
                height: 400,
                open: function(even, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).css("visibility","hidden");},
                title: "Nouvelle catégorie",
                resizable: false,
                hide:'slide',
                show:'slide',
                buttons:
                {
                    "Créer la catégorie":function()
                    {
                        var ok = true;
                        if(isNaN($('#ordreCategorie').val()) || $('#ordreCategorie').val().length < 1)
                        {
                            ok = false;
                            $('#ordreCategorie').css("background-color","#F00");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#ordreCategorie').css("background-color","#CF0");
                        }
                        if($('#nomCategorie').val().length< 3)
                        {
                            ok = false;
                            $('#nomCategorie').css("background-color","#F00");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#nomCategorie').css("background-color","#CF0");
                        }

                        if(ok)
                        {
                            var ordre = $('#ordreCategorie').val();
                            var nom = $('#nomCategorie').val();
                            $.getJSON('addCategory.php', {'ordre':ordre,'nom':nom}, function(data) 
                            {
                                console.log("THIS LOG WON'T APPEAR AND THE CODE WON'T EXECUTE.");
                                if( data.result === "false" )
                                {
                                    $('div id="Dialog_Feedback">Une catégorie porte déjà ce nom ou cet ordre!</div>').dialog(
                                    {
                                        autoOpen:false,
                                        title:'Une erreur est survenue!',
                                        width:200,
                                        height:'auto',
                                        resizable: false,
                                        modal:true,
                                        buttons:
                                        {
                                            "OK" : function()
                                            {
                                                $( this ).remove();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $('<div id="Dialog_Feedback">L\'ajout a été effectué avec succès!</div>').dialog({
                                        autoOpen:false,
                                        title:'Catégorie ajoutée!',
                                        width:400,
                                        height:'auto',
                                        resizable:false,
                                        modal:true,
                                        buttons:{
                                            "Ok": function()
                                            {
                                                $(this).remove();
                                                window.location.reload();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });                                 
                                }
                                $('#Dialog_Feedback').dialog("open");   
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    "Annuler":function()
                    {
                        $( this ).remove();
                    }
                }   
        });
```

Here is the `addCategory.php` page:

```
<?php
include('../../anything.php');
$nom = $_GET['nom'];
$ordre = $_GET['ordre'];
$sql = "SELECT ordre, nom FROM category";
$checking = mysql_query($sql);
$ok = true;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($checking))
{
    echo "test";
    if((strtolower($nom) === strtolower($row['nom'])) || ($ordre === $row['ordre']))
    {
        $ok = false;
    }
}
if ($ok)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO category (nom,ordre) VALUES('$nom',$ordre)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($connexion);
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>"true"));
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>"false"));
}
?>
```

Anyone has an idea of what may cause that? I have checked both variables sent in the GET and they contain something.

My PHP page returns JSON encoded results like this:

`echo json_encode(array("result"=>"true"));`

Thank you everyone for you time.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that **both** Chrome Inspector and Firebug don't report any errors in the whole script execution. The `console.log()` part also does not appear, meaning the commands in the PHP page are executed, but the javascript function contained inside the `$.get()` is not triggered.

**Edit2**: I also tried changing the `echo` calls to `echo true;` and `return true;`.

**Edit3**: I am able to see the results of the PHP page in the Network tab of Chrome Inspector and Firebug: `{"result":"false"}array(1) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(5) "false"
}`
It shows that the problem would reside into the `$.getJSON()` call! But everything seems fine to me!

Comment: Use Firebug to check the actual response from the server.

Comment: is the response coming from the same `Origin` as the web page?

Comment: Is the PHP script erroring out? Does anything appear in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: There is no response coming out at all. I can't even do a `console.log()` of the `data` variable since everything inside the function is not executed.

Comment: Actualy, there is one thing showing in the console: 

`XHR finished loading: "http://**epicLANip^**/somefolder/folder/folder/anotherOne/addCategorie.php?ordre=1773&nom=Bingo". ` 

Of course, change the values of the GET variables by something else.

Comment: So, according to your Edit #3, you're not getting back valid JSON, correct?  It is unsurprising that `$.getJSON` isn't calling its success callback when it isn't being given valid JSON.

Comment: @apsillers You sir are a genius. I deleted the echo "test"; part of the PHP page and it worked! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass invalid JSON to `$.getJSON`, the success callback will not be fired.  As you mentioned in your edit, you're getting back a response like `{"result":"false"}array(1) { ["result"]=> string(5) "false" }`, which is certainly not valid JSON.

Correct your script to produce valid JSON and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you again sir! This might be useful for more than my own self!